# How to upload image in python?

Tags: python, image, face-recognition

I was developing an app that returns JSON data if an uploaded image matches the image in the app folder.   After selecting a particular image, I click "Upload" image it shows "No file chosen". The below given whole code. How can I fix this up? Thank you, in advance!

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    # Check if a valid image file was uploaded
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)

    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <h1>Upload a picture for image recognition</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    '''

path = "Images"
images = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
#print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    
encodeList=[]

for img in images:
    encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
    encodeList.append(encode)
    print(encodeList)

def findEncodings(file_stream):

    img = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
    # Get face encodings for any faces in the uploaded image
    unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
    
    is_the_same_person = False

    if len(unknown_face_encodings) > 0:
        match_results = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeList, unknown_face_encodings)
        if match_results[0]:
            is_obama = True

    # Return the result as json
    result = {
        "is_the_same_person": same
    }
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `findEncodings()` is not being called anywhere. Does it serve any purpose or should it be removed from the code snippet?

Comment: @BubbleMaster   yes, you're right. I didn't call the function anywhere. I did it and it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome! I posted my first comment as an answer. Please accept it since it helped you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findEncodings()` is not being called anywhere. Does it serve any purpose or should it be removed from the code snippet?