# HTML using a form to add an image into a folder using python

Tags: python, html, forms, image

so i have a form that i am using an input with type file, I need an example of how could get this image that is selected and put it into a folder in a local directory

```
      <tr><td><label for=attachments>Attachments:</label></td>
      <td><input type=file name=attachments></td></tr>
```

how would i go about getting the image that is selected and making a copy of it in a directory using Python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965784/how-to-upload-image-in-python)